# AS3: Minimum value from that is not 0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem:
Is there any way I can find the minimum value of an Array that is not 0? Let's say I have this Array:

{0,2,0,0,1} and I want it to find 1.

Comment: Of course there is a way, multiple even. But people probably won't show you if you don't show what you've tried. How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be a slight variation on finding the minimum *including* zero. This would be achieved by setting the minimum to the first value and then going through all the others, replacing the minimum if a value in the array is lower.

The modification needed to that for your scenario is to just ignore those having a value of zero. Something like this should do:

```
var numbers:Array = [0,2,0,0,1];
var started:Boolean = false;
var minval:Number = 0;

for each (var num:Number in numbers) {
    if ((!started) && (num != 0)) {
        started = true;
        minval = num;
    }
    if ((started) && (num != 0) && (num < minval)) {
        minval = num;
    }
}
```

The first `if` statement will be the only one executed until you find the first non-zero value, at which point you'll set `started` and store that number as the minimum.

From then on (including on that iteration), you'll just check the non-zero numbers to see if they're less and store them if so.

At the end, either `started` will be `false` in which case there were no non-zero numbers, or `started` will be `true` and `minval` will hold the smallest number found.

Comment: @Coder if you initialise `minval` with `infinity` instead of 0, you don't have to treat the first value differently and the loop body simplifies to `if((num != 0) && (num < minval))  minval = num;` When the result is Infinity, you won't be able to tell if Infinity was the only other element that was not 0 or if there was no other element at all. Depending on if you need that edge case, you can use this simplification (or not)